# How can I use routes .php in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a question with routes in Symfony2.

Now, my website work fine there:

```
www.mywebsite.com/products
```

But, I want that the web works fine there and with a trailing .php

```
www.mywebsite.com/products.php
```

How can I do this with Syfmony2?

Comment: Declare a new route pattern `/products.php` which will reroute to `/products` ?

Comment: Why? Doesn't look good ^^

Answer (score 0):

putting in route:

```
pattern:  /products.php
```

if doesn't work check nginx/apache settings

Comment: Thanks all, using two rules works fine, but i would like do this with only one rule, is possible?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, witch two roles? Witch one rule?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
products:
  pattern: /products{ext}
  requirements:
    ext: "(\.php)?"
```